# Any suggestions regarding this image i shared where a specific output voltage is required to specific input. No microcontroller should be used

Tags: voltage, dc, signal, conditioning

[image: mV input vs mV Output]

Please see this image. As you can see from 0 to 999mV the output should be 0 to 100mV(this can be achieved easily) but when the input changes from 999 to 1000 and further the output should be from 10mV to 100mV. Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: @Transistor I think this might simply be a bug of the new markdown engine of SE, it requires an empty line between content and URL lists.

Comment: First see if you can notice the pattern in the input specification. Then identify steps that will allow you to accomplish the task. Then design circuitry fer each step.

Comment: Why do you want this?  The problem and the no-MCU restriction seem absurd, you're going to have to justify the need, and in so doing will reveal clues key to either selecting an actually viable solution, or rejecting the entire idea as unsound.

Comment: Dear Chris, using a mcu is easy but how to do it in old fashioned way, i want to know it...by the way this is used for 7017 IC.

Comment: Why would you want to know how to do something that makes no sense for noise reasons? Either, this is an XY problem (i.e. you think this is a solution to a problem you're not telling us about, but it's actually not a solution at all), or you're trying to distract from the fact that this is homework.

Comment: Are you going to build this circuit and use it? Please give simple yes or no answer.

Comment: Not at all sir, this is an honest problem which is bugging me. As you can see this is not a linear output vs input graph. I tried sedra smith but they all are linear circuits. Any book or online reference regarding such non linear signal  conditioning circuit  is appreciated. I will try to learn from it.

Comment: Definitely. No doubt.

Comment: You have two segments. Both are linear. One of them is a divide by 10, and the other is a divide by 100. So you can create a V/10 circuit using a voltage divider, and a V/100 using another voltage divider. Then you can choose which one you want using a comparator and mux. You will have to decide on how much error tolerance you can allow and do all the error analysis. Hysteresis when switching from one signal to the other will also be a problem that needs attention.

Comment: @RajKiran your description is incomplete, you missed the section between 999 and 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a conceptual diagram. This is not a real schematic. It is just to give you the idea. There are many problems with this idea that others have touched upon. So make sure you allocate a lot of time for debugging the circuit. The biggest problem I see is that you will HAVE to have hysteresis in the switchover, otherwise the output will swing back and forth between 0.1 and 0.01V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f84e6w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Dear @mkeith But mux is binary, How will it so these low voltage lines at Output. Are u suggesting analog multiplexer......

Comment: Yes. It must be an analog multiplexer. But I didn't see a symbol for an analog multiplexer so I used the digital one.

Comment: I was thinking of two mosfets and a demux to select different outputs

Comment: Might work, but you may be able to reduce design/debug time by using an off-the-shelf analog switch. One thing to consider is capacitive coupling between input and output. This can reduce isolation of a single transistor switch at AC. Chip designers will take steps to improve this. You can too, but it adds complexity and discrete part count.

Comment: Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 2):

You can logically build that from comparators, and adders (both can be built using operational amplifiers), and voltage references. (That's enough hints; this clearly is homework.)

Notice that after building this, you'll notice how much of a terrible idea this is; if your voltage is somewhere between say 998 mV and 1002 mV and you have say a 10 mV RMS noise (which isn't really much), imagine how badly your output would be jumping! I doubt this specification has any practical use but to teach you basic opamp circuitry, and how to build a system from logical components like summers, comparators.

However, this is a trick question: You're building a device that has < 1 mV of accuracy. Not a trivial thing to do with standard components.

While selecting your opamps, you will have to take input offsets into account; when selecting voltage standards, you will have to pick ones that are accurate enough. So, you'd instantly fail if you're trying to do that with an xx741 opamp and an uncompensated zener!

Getting precision resistors and voltage references will be key here, and so will be designing your feedback such that variations don't add constructively.

Comment: Dear sir any reference online links are appreciated. I tried on goggle but couldnt found.

Comment: that's not something you can google. You know basic opamp circuits, this is such a typical excercise for students that have learned these, so apply that knowledge.